# ios how to hide one uiview and push another uiview at the same position

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I want to set **myview** hidden and **view** visible, how can I do this. This is the code I got so far but it makes everything hidden.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(185, 960, 768, 1004); 
HiUIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.myview addSubview:view];
[self.myview setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: When you hide a view you hide all its subviews.  Them's the rules.

Comment: Why are you hiding a view that has subviews you wish to show?

Comment: ok how would i hide one view and push another view at the same position.

Comment: myview is the superview of view , when u hide myview, view disappears too.

Comment: your 2 view should be subview of another view!

Answer (score 4):

You are adding a view inside another and then hide the second. The first is child of the second, so is hidden too.

You can try adding "view" in the parent of "myview".

Answer (score 1):

why not put both views in a container? let the current vc's view be the container of your views.

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.myview.frame];
[self.view addSubView:self.myview];
[self.view addSubView:view];
self.myview.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead in your sample:

```
[self.myview setHidden:YES];
```

make

```
[self.myview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are adding a view to myView and then hiding the parent view i.e. myview in your case ,Use this

```
UIView *_viewTmp = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:myview.frame];
[myview.superview addSubview:_viewTmp];
myview.hidden = YES;
```

I hope this will help.